# Roll back to an old commit, but apply back my commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have been working on a feature branch `A` that I merged to `dev` branch. I made several more commits to the `dev` branch after merge. However, I realized that the current head of `dev` branch is broken and would like to test my `A` branch by rolling back to a certain commit in `dev` branch and re-applying all the commits of `A` and extra ones I did after merge in `dev`. How could I achieve this?

EDIT: Many people have committed to `dev`, and I merged in my branch `A` which is composed of only my commits. Basically, I want to remove the commits of all other people upto certain old commit.

The rollback is for testing purpose only to see if branch A is somewhat compatible with branch `dev`. It doesn't need to be "up-to-date", but need A to merge onto a certain point in `dev` where the code actually used to work.

Comment: Look into using `git filter-branch`.  There is no quick fix to your problem.  If you just want to test something, you could checkout the old commit, redo the merge and new commits, test, and then decide whether you want to keep it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the quick response! Do you mean merge in from branch `A` or branch `dev`? If former, I would still need a way to merge in the new commits of `dev`. If latter, that would undo the rollback, right? Since it will try to merge in all the commits not including mine.

Comment: I actually realized while writing the above comment that I left a crucial information. Many people have committed to `dev`, and I merged in my branch `A` which is composed of only my commits. Basically, I want to remove the commits of all other people upto certain old commit.

Comment: You're basically suggesting rewriting the history of the `dev` branch.  Your options include `git rebase` in interactive mode and `git filter-branch`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sorry about missing vital information again, but it's more testing purpose only to see if branch `A` is somewhat compatible with branch `dev`. It doesn't need to be "up-to-date", but need `A` to merge onto a certain point in `dev` where the code actually used to work.

Comment: Just checkout the previous commit in the detached HEAD state via `git checkout <SHA-1>`, then do your compatibility tests.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But the main problem is to merge in the branch `A` and the extra commits I did on top of the merging `A` and `dev`. I need all of my commits including the ones I did after merging for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary branch.

Let's draw what you have now, as a series of commits on branch `dev` and your `feature` branch.  Let's assume for the moment that you *haven't* merged your `feature` branch into `dev` (even though you have, i.e., let's start from just before you did `git checkout dev && git merge feature`):

```
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E--F      <-- dev
         \
          G---H--I--J--K---L     <-- feature
```

Now, you already did `git checkout dev && git merge feature` or equivalent, so let's add the merge commit to the drawing:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E--F--M   <-- dev
         \                  /
          G---H--I--J--K---L     <-- feature
```

"Your" commits are the ones on branch `feature` that are not also on `dev` before the merge, i.e., `G` through `L`, plus of course your new merge `M`.

Now you say you have added several more commits as well, so let's draw them in:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E--F--M--N--O    <-- dev
         \                  /
          G---H--I--J--K---L            <-- feature
```

It's at this point that you realized that something is broken in, say, `E` and maybe `F` as well.  So now you want to see what happens if you test "commit `O` as it would be if we didn't have commits `E` and/or `F`".

#### Method one: make temporary branch and revert bad commits

(This is usually the easiest method.  You already did the merge; the other method makes you re-do the merge, and merges tend to be a bit harder than reverts.)

Step 1 is to get a temporary branch.  While on `dev`, simply `git checkout -b temp`, so that you now have:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E--F--M--N--O    <-- dev, HEAD -> temp
         \                  /
          G---H--I--J--K---L            <-- feature
```

Now you can run `git revert <id-of-E> <id-of-F>` to revert the two "bad" commits.  This does what `git cherry-pick` does, except in reverse: it finds out what changed from `E` to `F` (so that it can be repeated, or in this case, un-done) and "reverse applies" that change to un-do it.  Then it finds out what changed from `D` to `E`, in the same way, and reverse-applies that change to undo it as well.

Now you have:

```
                                     f'-e'  <-- temp
                                    /
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E--F--M--N--O        <-- dev
         \                  /
          G---H--I--J--K---L                <-- feature
```

where `f'` is the commit that "undoes" `F`, and `e'` is the commit that "undoes" `E`.

Now you can run your tests.

#### Method two: make temporary branch, then re-merge and cherry-pick

Again, we start with the idea that `E` and `F` are "bad".  So this time, we want a temporary branch that points directly to commit `D`: the last "good" commit on `dev`.  Find the ID of commit `D` and then:

```
git checkout -b temp <id-of-D>
```

Now you have this—which is the same drawing as before, but we've added a bump "up" for the new branch label:

```
                   D                  <-- HEAD -> temp
                  / \
...--o--*--A--B--C   E--F--M--N--O    <-- dev
         \                /
          G--H--I--J--K--L            <-- feature
```

Now run `git merge feature`.  This makes a *new* merge commit, quite different from `M`, that merges commit `L` into commit `D`.  Drawing the resulting graph is a bit difficult since the merge line crosses over the `dev` branch (I should have taken a different approach than lifting `D` up a line), but here's a sort of stab at it:

```
                   D-------m          <-- HEAD -> temp
                  / \     .
...--o--*--A--B--C   E--F--M--N--O    <-- dev
         \               ./
          G--H--I--J--K--L            <-- feature
```

Now use `git cherry-pick` to *copy* commits `N` and `O`.  This is similar to our earlier `revert`, except that it doesn't try to "undo" the changes, but instead just to copy them.  Let's call these copies `N'` and `O'` (uppercase since they're copies, not reverse-copies):

```
                   D-------m--N'--O'  <-- HEAD -> temp
                  / \     .
...--o--*--A--B--C   E--F--M--N--O    <-- dev
         \               ./
          G--H--I--J--K--L            <-- feature
```

Now run your tests as before.

#### What if the tests fail?

If things still don't work, it's up to you to decide how to deal with that.  However, you can continue to make *new* commits on your `temp` branch until you have fixed things, then decide how to collect up those fixes and either rework `feature`, or add them after commit `O`, or whatever.  This particular part is really easy, because you have a branch!